# Selecting elements in XSLT based on attributes using .NET

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm writing an application in C# using .NET Framework 3.5 to implement a series of transforms.  I'm using the XslCompiledTransform class to perform the transforms. I'd like to avoid writing a bunch of for-each statements in my XSLT transforms so I'd like to select some data based on an attribute.  My source data looks as follows.

```
<Radios>
      <Radio name="UHF1">
        <GUID protected="true">785A9539-918B-4DCE-A9AA-AC9D6275EA86</GUID>
        <DigitalAudioDeviceInstance protected="true">1</DigitalAudioDeviceInstance>
        <DigitalAudioDevicePort>2</DigitalAudioDevicePort>
        <ACIMLocalInstance protected="true">1</ACIMLocalInstance>
        <ACIMLocalPort>2</ACIMLocalPort>
        <ACIMSCCInstance protected="true">1</ACIMSCCInstance>
      </Radio>
      <Radio name="VHF1">
        <GUID protected="true">C150EA26-E53E-4366-B4A0-84BF619BFD3A</GUID>
        <DigitalAudioDeviceInstance protected="true">2</DigitalAudioDeviceInstance>
        <DigitalAudioDevicePort>2</DigitalAudioDevicePort>
        <ACIMLocalInstance protected="true">2</ACIMLocalInstance>
        <ACIMLocalPort>6</ACIMLocalPort>
        <ACIMSCCInstance protected="true">2</ACIMSCCInstance>
      </Radio>
    </Radios>
```

I'm using the following to trying to reference the "ACIMSCCInstance" from a Radio:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Radios/Radio/ACIMSCCInstance[@name=UHF1]"/>
```

This is not working however Keep in mind that "Radios" is NOT the root of the document, and I am in fact at the appropriate level where this relative path should work.  Just to make sure I tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Radios/Radio/ACIMSCCInstance"/>
```

Which of course gives me the "ACIMSCCInstance" value ("1") of the first radio in the list.

My Question is, why doesn't the "[@name=UHF1]" at the end of the path work at picking the radio with the name "UHF1".  I've also tried this "@name='UHF1']" and no dice.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the problems and a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using the following to trying to
>   reference the "ACIMSCCInstance" from a
>   Radio:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="Radios/Radio/ACIMSCCInstance[@name=UHF1]"/>
> ```
>
> This is not working however
>
> My Question is, why doesn't the
>   "[@name=UHF1]" at the end of the path
>   work at picking the radio with the
>   name "UHF1

**The XPath expression**:

```
Radios/Radio/ACIMSCCInstance[@name=UHF1]
```

selects all `ACIMSCCInstance` elements whose `name` attribute is equal to the string value of at least one of the children-elements of `ACIMSCCInstance` that are named `UHF1`. Also this `ACIMSCCInstance` element must be a child of a `Radio` element and this must be a child of an `Radios` element and this must be a child of the current node.

**There are at least two serious mistakes in this expression**:

1. **There isn't any element named `UHF1` in the whole document**. You want to compare with the *string* literal `'UHF1'` and string literals in XPath must be surrounded by either single or double quotes.
2. **No `ACIMSCCInstance` element in the document has a `name` attribute**. You actually want this test to be done for the `Radio` element.

**Solution**:

Fixing the two problems above gives us the following correct XPath expression:

```
Radios/Radio[@name='UHF1']/ACIMSCCInstance
```

**Recommendation**: Reading a good book on XPath is necessary for acquiring the basic knowledge necessary for working with XSLT.

Comment: +1 for helpful answer. 2 things: (1) in the upper middle you have a typo, `UHF` instead of `UHF1`. (2) @Ultratrunks: this mistake of forgetting the quotes and (in effect) accidentally using an element name that doesn't exist is an insidious problem of XPath. Most programming languages would throw an error, "No such variable UHF1". But XPath can't detect that your input document has no UHF1 element, unless it knows about the structure of the input document. For this you need a schema-aware XSLT dev environment.

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks for this observation -- I edited my answer. As for the benefits of SA XSLT/XPath, yes, they are really nice. My observations show that SA is being embraced very slowly -- partly due to lack of free and good implementations, but even more due to lack of knowledge and experience among users.

Comment: Nice, this worked.  Just a bone head mistake I couldn't see with my own two eyes.